# How to send data through TCPServer from another thread

Tags: python

I'm writing a server in Python, which should basicaly work as a pipe between some serial device (like Arduino) and any client connected to it.

```
import SocketServer
import threading
import errno

def SerialThread():
    # Serial init is here
    while (True):
        msg = read_from_serial(blocking = True)
        #print(msg)
        try:
            server.socket.sendall(str(msg))
        except IOError, e:
            if e.errno == errno.EPIPE:
                print('Server not ready')

serial_daemon = threading.Thread(name='SerialThread', target=SerialThread)
serial_daemon.daemon = True
serial_daemon.start()

class TCPHandler(SocketServer.StreamRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        print('#')

server = SocketServer.TCPServer(('127.0.0.1', 4242), TCPHandler)
print('Starting server')
server.serve_forever()
```

But I keep getting `Server not ready` spammed in my console. So what's wrong with my code, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

`TCPServer.socket` is in "listen" mode, you can not use it to trans data directly, you need "connect" to its address with a new socket object:

```
import socket

while 1:
    s = socket.create_connection(('127.0.0.1', 4242))
    s.sendall(str(msg))
```

depends on how your server handle connection, you could reuse the same socket or create a new one every loop.